# What is considered a 'good' running time for short running distances for a normal fit person?

Tags: running

I have been exercising to improve my time for distances from 100m to 1km for the past two months, and I feel that I have made a decent amount of progress. However, I get a feeling that even my new times are quite slow relative to other people about my age who practice running. So, referring to coaches and maybe people who have access to useful statistics, what is considered an average *good* time, among people the age from 17 to 20, who practice running regularly on an amateur level for (any of) the following distances: 100m, 400m, 800m, 1000m?

For the purposes of comparison, here are my record running times:

- 100m  - 11.9 secconds
- 400m  - 59 seconds
- 800m  - 2 minutes 10 seconds
- 1000m - 2 minutes 45 seconds

Also, please don't be afraid to be as harsh as possible and be as truthful as you can - i.e. even if my times are absolutely awful for my age, please say it.

Comment: This question appears to be about competitive running, so it is on topic for this site. It has a clearly defined scope. It is useful to other users, as they can compare their times against those both Max and the answer have provided. Max has made enough effort here to at least receive an explanation for the downvotes. Drive-by downvoting should probably be reserved for very poor questions, which this one is not.

Comment: Thank you. The intent of this question was purely to receive an answer and get information. Perhaps, the question does not follow some StackExchange formalities as to how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are good times. Here are [State Qualifying](https://www.ihsa.org/documents/trb/2016-17/2017%20TRB%20Qualifying%20Standards.pdf) times for Illinois High School Boys. You aren't quite to these levels, but you are certainly well above average times for your age.

My personal experience around runners of that age is that nobody will judge you, disrespect you, or think less of you for those times.

EDIT: There is some confusion in the comments. These are the qualifying times for the State Finals for High School Boys in Illinois. The State Finals are the highest level of competition available for a high school athlete. If you run ANY of these times, you should be considered exceptional at that race. There is nothing specific about Illinois, I just chose a state I was familiar with. Every state will have slightly different qualifications.

For reference, there are less than 100 athletes that make these times each year, for the entire state of IL which has a population of 12 million.

Comment: Unfortunately, the website doesn't open for me. Also, what is so special about the Illinois State School?

Comment: It's a PDF, not a website! Nothing is particularly special about Illinois, it's just a reasonable reference point to use; you asked for "useful statistics" - this seems a useful reference point to me.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed useful statistics, for which I am thankful. However, Frank Anderson stated that 'you aren't quite to these levels, but you are certainly well above average times for your age', which implies that Illinois High School Boys is also well above average. So what I am asking is: why is so well above average? PS I couldn't know that it's PDF because it wasn't opening! But thanks.